# replace <SOAP-ENC:Struct> / repeated elements in php soap

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I wrote the following code:

```
<?php
$array = array();
$array[] = new Inventory(50,"Mr. P. Erson");
$array[] = new Inventory(51,"Mrs. F. Emale");


$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/logistics/wsdl/logisticsService2.wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
$client->addPickticket($array);

echo $client->__getLastRequest();

class Inventory {
    public $Sku;
    public $Description;

    public function __construct($sku,$desc) {
        $this->Sku = $sku;
        $this->Description = $desc;
    }
}
?>
```

this produces the following soap-envelope:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://logistics.website.eu" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:addPickTicket><PickTicket>
        <SOAP-ENC:Struct>
            <Sku>50</Sku>
            <Description>Mr. P. Erson</Description>
        </SOAP-ENC:Struct>
        <SOAP-ENC:Struct>
            <Sku>51</Sku>
            <Description>Mrs. F. Emale</Description>
        </SOAP-ENC:Struct>
    </PickTicket></ns1:addPickTicket></SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I replace this `<SOAP-ENC:Struct>` by some self-chosen name?
I know it's quite obvious now that it doesn't fill in any name; I don't specify this name anywhere but I can't really find out how to do this. I definitely need this because I want multiple elements with the same name, so a simple array won't work; I wouldn't be able to add multiple items with the same name.

Comment: Use Zend SOAP lib instead of the SOAP extension.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24009116/607033

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922620/wsdl-problem-with-php-objects-strange-soap-encstruct-elements or http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/33914-soap-webservice-how-to-remove-return-struc-field/ ?

Comment: I'll look into Zend. Is it easy to use multiple elements with the same name then? I don't directly see how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in a combination of these 2:

- http://andrecatita.com/code-snippets/php-soap-repeated-element-name/
- http://www.fischco.org/blog/2011/3/26/php-soapserver-objects-arrays-and-encoding.html

resulting in the following (example)code:

```
<?php
// Note, this is a method which can be used in simple and complex responses

$dogParams = new ArrayObject(); // Dog Parameters
$dogs = new ArrayObject(); // Dog Element
$competition = new stdClass(); // Competition Element
$namespace="";

// * Note the hard-coded 0, because this is an example
$dogParams[0]->Gender = 'Male';
$dogParams[0]->Breed = 'Aidi';

// If you are building a complex response, you could have gone for this
// example using a SoapVar
$dogParams[1]->Gender = new SoapVar("Female", XSD_STRING, NULL, $namespace, 'Gender', $namespace);
$dogParams[1]->Breed= new SoapVar("Labrador", XSD_STRING, NULL, $namespace, 'Breed', $namespace);

$dog0 = new SoapVar($dogParams[0],SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,NULL,$namespace,'Dog',$namespace);
$dog1 = new SoapVar($dogParams[1],SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,NULL,$namespace,'Dog',$namespace);

// Now that we have two (2) dogs information, simply append to 'Dogs'

$dogs->append($dog0);
$dogs->append($dog1);

// And now our outside structure, Competition element
$competition->Dogs = new SoapVar($dogs, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $namespace, 'Dogs ', $namespace);


$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/logistics/wsdl/logisticsService2.wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
$client->OutgoingNoosGoodsOrder($competition);
echo $client->__getLastRequest();
?>
```

this results in the following soap envelope:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://logistics.website.eu">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:OutgoingNoosGoodsOrder>
            <PickTicket>
                <Dogs>
                    <Dog>
                        <Gender>Male</Gender>
                        <Breed>Aidi</Breed>
                    </Dog>
                    <Dog>
                        <Gender>Female</Gender>
                        <Breed>Labrador</Breed>
                    </Dog>
                </Dogs>
            </PickTicket>
        </ns1:OutgoingNoosGoodsOrder>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

(Please note; OutgoingNoosGoodsOrder and Pickticket are terms that come from my (temp) wsdl file.)